# Query polygon layer by geometry size

Tags: qgis, geometry, query

This is something I know I can do with ArcGIS but I don't know how to perform on QGIS.
I have a layer containing multiple polygons of size x. I want to query the layer to remove every polygon of size less than 1 km2. How do I accomplish this on QGIS?

Comment: If you wish to merely not show them then you can apply a definition query either by right clicking on a layer and choosing Filter or in the Layer Properties - Source - Provider Feature Filter create a Query on your area field  You can also click on the tables Show All Features and instead apply a filter .  If you wish to select polygons for deletion use a selection query in the table on the area field and delete in an edit session.  There is also a Select by Attribute Processing tool.  This all assumes you have an area field to use in the query.

Comment: If you want to modify the layer: use the Select by expression tool. In the Expression textbox type the following: $area/1000000 < 1
Once, selected, edit layer and delete the features.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the layer --> Filter

[image]

Enter your query

[image]

It doesn't work if your layer is in the edit mode

In Arcgis it is a little bit more logical that the defintion qurey is in the property window/menu.